# Map, catch error and assign with Combine in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I learn to use Combine and I wrote this code:

```swift
        serviceAgent.podcasts()
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { cpl in
                    switch cpl {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    case .finished:
                       return
                    }
                },
                receiveValue: { [weak self] (model) in
                    self?.items = model.map({ podcast in
                        let item = PodcastCardItemViewModel(podcast)
                        item.clickPublisher.sink { value in
                            self?.clickPublisher.send(value)
                        }.store(in: &(self!.cancelBag))
                        return item
                    })
                }
            ).store(in: &cancelBag)
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible to simplify this code with map, catch and assign but I don't know how.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Advanced Combine

This is some of the hard stuff with combine. But it is doable. Without seeing the rest of your code, I don't know if this will work 100% correctly. But I was able to get this to compile on my machine.

```swift
serviceAgent
  .podcasts()
  .map(PodcastCardItemViewModel.init)
  .flatMap { $0.clickPublisher }
  .collect()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  .sink(
    receiveCompletion: { cpl in
    switch cpl {
    case .failure(let error):
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    case .finished:
      return
    }
  },
    receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
    self?.clickPublisher.send(value)
  }
  ).store(in: &cancelBag)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using sink

Comment: With combine, you have to resolve the pipeline at some point. Either sink or subscribe. That is was executes the function. If you want the sink to occur somewhere else, you could do the send in another `.map` and return the resulting publisher from a function for sinking elsewhere.